# Husband withholds intimacy from one wife but maintains relations with his other wife

Tags: husband-wife, polygamy

Assalamu alaikum,

I am in a polygamous marriage and we all live together in one house.  I would like to know whether it is permissible for a husband to withhold relations from one wife but have relations with another?  My husband has not been intimate with me for 3 months but has relations with the other wife with me in the house.  I know this because I can hear them making ghusl.
I work and contribute my entire salary to him for everything that needs to be paid while the other wife has not worked in over a year and is pregnant.  She is to give birth any day now.

Please can someone assist me.  What are my options because it feels like I am only there to help pay the bills while the other wife has rights that I obviously do not have.

I would love to have a child but how will this be possible when my husband refuses to touch me?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't owe any maintenance\money to your husband, rather your husband owes maintenance to you, its called *nafqah* and is an integral part of marriage.

> [Quran 2:233](https://quran.com/2/233) ... Upon the father is their provision and clothing
>   according to what is acceptable ...
>
> [Quran 65:6](https://quran.com/65/6) Lodge them [in a section] of where you dwell out of your
>   means and do not harm them in order to oppress them. And if they
>   should be pregnant, then spend on them until they give birth. And if
>   they breastfeed for you, then give them their payment and confer among
>   yourselves in the acceptable way; but if you are in discord, then
>   there may breastfeed for the father another woman.
>
> [Quran 65:7](https://quran.com/65/7) Let a man of wealth spend from his wealth, and he whose
>   provision is restricted - let him spend from what Allah has given him.
>   Allah does not charge a soul except [according to] what He has given
>   it. Allah will bring about, after hardship, ease.
>
> [Quran 4:34](https://quran.com/4/34) Men are in charge of women by [right of] what Allah has
>   given one over the other and what they spend [for maintenance] from
>   their wealth.

Secondly, its your husband's obligation to spend time equally between his wives, it is a precondition of permitting him polygamy.

> [Quran 4:3](https://quran.com/4/3) ... marry those that please you of [other] women, two
>   or three or four. But if you fear that you will not be just, then
>   [marry only] one or those your right hand possesses. That is more
>   suitable that you may not incline [to injustice].
>
> [Quran 4:129](https://quran.com/4/129) And you will never be able to be equal [in feeling]
>   between wives, even if you should strive [to do so]. So do not incline
>   completely [toward one] and leave another hanging.
>
> عن عائِشة، قالت كان رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم يقسم بين نسايه ثم
>   يعدل ثم يقول ‏ "‏ اللهم هذا فعلي فيما املك فلا تلمني فيما تملك ولا
>   املك
>
> Aishah said: "The Messenger of Allah used to divide his time equally
>   among his wives, then he would say 'O Allah, this is what I am doing
>   with regard to that which is within my control, so do not hold me
>   accountable for that which is under Your control and is beyond my
>   control.'"
>    <sub>[Sunan Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/12/89), [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1320480), [Sunan Nisai](https://sunnah.com/nasai/36/5), [Jami Tirmizi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/11/62)</sub>

Thirdly, advice on how to remedy this situation is relationship counseling and opinion based and we don't delve into that here. Options could include:

1. Talking with your husband, admonishing him of your rights.
2. Getting a third party involved, such as parents\relatives etc.
3. Seeking separation.

Answer (score 0):

Clear case of injustice.

Husband has to spend alternate nights between 2 wives, spend his wealth equally on both wives.

Take him to a Muslim judge if he doesn't improve after advice and warning